# Matrix field total_rows > 0 not working?

Tags: matrix

I'm trying to display a matrix field ONLY if it has data entered into it.

I've tried this by wrapping it in this conditional...

```
{if mymatrix:total_rows > 0}
  {mymatrix}
    data here
  {/mymatrix}
{/if}
```

But nothing is getting outputted. If I remove the conditional, the matrix is outputted fine. Any ideas? (I'm up to date with EE 2.9.2 & Matrix version 2.6.1)

Comment: I've been having some issues with conditionals lately. Does this work? `{if "{mymatrix:total_rows}" > 0}`

Comment: Yup, this worked for me! Thanks! Do you want to add it as an answer and I can mark it as so. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're having trouble with tags not working correctly in conditional statements try wrapping the them in double or single quotation marks.

```
{if "{mymatrix:total_rows}" > 0}{!-- Here --}
  {mymatrix}
    data here
  {/mymatrix}
{/if}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  This should work for you (it did for me).

```
{if {mymatrix:total_rows} > 0 }
{mymatrix}
data here
{/mymatrix}
{/if}
```

Does the template work without the {if} statements?  You may also try wrapping the zero in a single quote ( '0' ).

Comment: Didn't work for me. I get a "This URL cannot be processed" when I tried this.

Comment: Yes the templates work without the conditionals. The suggestion from Kieran seemed to work fine. Thanks!